# Excel formulas that account for merged cell data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a nutshell, I have a project tracker that looks like this (simplified):

[image: Project tracker]

Col D is desired output. I need it to calculate total hours spent per project, which is obviously simple math, but each project in Col A is a merged cell and can have a random number of people contributing.

Without changing format, is there a clever way to write a single formula such that it knows how many people belong to each project and can calculate totals?

Comment: The easy option is to add a hidden helper column that repeats the project number, in `E2` for example: `=IF(A2<>"",A2,E1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in D2 and copy down:

```
=IF(A2="",D1,SUM(C2:INDEX(C:C,IFERROR(MATCH("*",A3:$A$1040000,0)+ROW(A3)-2,MATCH(1E+99,C:C)))))
```

[image]